# Migrate my question: will I get the reputation back?

Tags: discussion, support, migration

This question didn't have luck here:

[How to do block-comments in Google Colab on a Mac with a non-American keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71980693/how-to-do-block-comments-in-google-colab-on-a-mac-with-a-non-american-keyboard)

There's also a closing vote, that suggests to move it to [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour). It seems a pretty good idea: there are other similar questions here

[Is it possible to do block-comments in Google Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59536088/is-it-possible-to-do-block-comments-in-google-colab/59567365#59567365)

which is why (I think) it wasn't closed. But still, if moving my question to Super User can help me get an answer, why not? Can the moderators do that, or do I need to delete this question and create an identical one on Super User? Also, would I recover the reputation lost? I only got 1 negative vote, so I guess that's not much in terms of reputation (2 points, maybe?) Anyway, if it's possible to get it back, why not?

Comment: That close vote seems wrong imo. Google Colab is a tool used for programming, commenting out lines is a typical thing a programmer would do. It might be on-topic on Super User/Ask Different/Web Apps/Etc as well, but that's not a reason to close it here.

Comment: It looks like the answer you are looking for would just as well fit to the original question – there are already several specifically for Mac, in fact. When existing answers are not sufficient, a bounty might be better than a separate question.

Comment: Seems like a good question to me. Kind of broken that you can't change the keyboard shortcut, or configure an alternative. Might be worth a bug report to be honest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moderators can migrate a question to another Stack Exchange site (which you could request with a moderator flag), but there's no point in doing so when you haven't received any answers and it's your own question. Just delete from here and repost over there.

Deleting it would recover the reputation lost from downvotes, as well as remove the reputation gained from upvotes (if any). Migration alone wouldn't have that effect, unless the post were also deleted. Deletion of a post always recalculates your reputation, clearing any reputation that was earned/removed from that post (including the rep others may have earned through suggesting edits that were approved).

Note that there is no requirement to delete or migrate that question, as it is not off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions about tools primarily used by programmers are on-topic here, so that would include Google Colab. (You can still delete it from here and ask it somewhere else, if you like. There is often some overlap in the scope of different Stack Exchange sites, and so it is always the asker's choice where they want to ask it, based on where they think it'll get the best answer.)

Comment: _"Migration alone wouldn't have that effect, unless the post were also deleted"_ Aren't migrated questions automatically deleted after some time? Or has this rule changed at some point?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine yes, [roomba'd after 30 days](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. BTW, in the end I was able to find a solution myself. I wrote an answer and I'll wait a bit before accepting it, in case someone finds a better one (unlikely, since my solution is very simple).

Comment: Great! Thanks for posting an answer. The system actually forces you to wait a bit before it allows you to accept your own answer (48 hours, if I remember correctly). That's designed for exactly the reason you mention. However, you should not worry too much about this. The entire principle of the site is that if anyone ends up on the question later with a better solution, they should post it, regardless of whether an answer has been accepted. The only questions that no longer accept answers are those which have been "closed", and questions are only closed here because they're unsuitable. @Delta

Answer (score 5):

The question has no answers so there's nothing much lost with deleting it here and reasking it somewhere else if you think you'll get a better reception in a new home. There is a no cross-posting rule but that just means that you can't have it visible in two places.

Note that just because it has one close vote doesn't mean it will automatically be closed. You could choose simply to wait and see whether it's answered. After all a single close vote is only one person's opinion.

Deleting and reasking is all under your control so it will be faster than flagging and then waiting and hoping that moderators help you out with something you can really accomplish yourself.

If you delete the question then all the votes on it will no longer affect your reputation. You will likely get more votes now that you've pointed people to the question with this Meta post. Sometimes the magnifying glass works in your favour, sometimes it doesn't - known as the [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect).

Comment: While you will get the reputation you lost, returned to you, the downvotes are still considered in any quality checks that might exist. Deleting your own question should be the last thing you attempt, it should be a rear event, deleting a question because it was well received is not considered a positive event with regards to the quality checks on contributions. Given the mix reception you might be better on focusing on the question you asked instead of deleting it or trying to get it to be migrated to another community without improvement.

Comment: @SecurityHound probably not so much of an issue deleting the odd question or two at 4K reputation.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for the answer, I didn't know about the meta effect. Well, knowing a bit about SE, I could have _imagined_ that there would be a meta effect, but honestly that's not the reason why I asked here. BTW, in meantime I found a simple answer to my own question. I'll wait a little bit for someone else to post their own answer, otherwise I'll accept my own